# Scrapy Response returning blank

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy

I am starting to learn Scrapy here and I am struggling to get a response back.
Here is my code:

```
fetch("https://www.mtgstocks.com/analytics/mostplayed")
```

After running this I received a Crawled (200) which one would expect.

However, When I ran

```
view(response)
```

I get a page that keeps on spinning and never loads. I looked up possible solutions on Stack Overflow and they mention that some sites need the user. I even did it with the User_Agent and I get the same result.

I also attempted:

```
response.xpath('//td')
response.xpath('//tr')
response.xpath('.//*[@class="wrapper"]').text()
response.xpath('.//*[@class="text-center"]')
```

and I get blank for all of them. Any Ideas or suggestions is appreciated.

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So this is a website that relies heavily on javascript. How do I know this ? Well it has quite a lot of functionality, but to be sure about what you can and can't get from making an pure HTTP request, you can disable javascript in your browser. In chrome inspect page --> click the three dots --> more tools --> settings --> Disable javascript.

You see a progress wheel spinning, because all the information is invoked by javascript to the API endpoint. The response renders the content of the page.

To look at how these request are made, inspecting the page --> network tools --> XHR. There are a bunch of requests, I tend to order them by size, then go through one by one when you click one of the requests you can see a tab called preview which previews the data. XHR btw refers to XML HTTP Request, this is an API that transfers an data from client to server.

I can see the requests that named by numbers have the table data you require.

Here is an example

[image]

You can then mimic these HTTP requests, javascript is invoking to get the data you want. This API is actually quite simple, it relies on no headers, parameters, queries, cookies to obtain the data. A simple HTTP get requests is all that is required.

In chrome dev tools, you can see the request URL, I usually play around with it with the requests package. You get a JSON object back from this HTTP Request which can then be manipulated like a dictionary to get the information you want. You haven't specified your data needs.

This technique of doing this is called re-engineering the HTTP request, it is the most efficient way to get dynamic content from a web page.

In scrapy something like this

### Code Example

```
def start_urls(self):
    url = 'https://api.mtgstocks.com/analytics/mostplayed/1'
    yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse) 

def parse(self,response):
    response.json()
```

### Output

```
{'format': {'id': 1, 'name': 'Legacy'},
 'mostplayed': [{'quantity': 660,
   'card': {'name': 'Brainstorm',
    'print': {'id': 55408,
     'latest_price': {'date': 1598250758000, 'avg': 0.5},
     'image': 'https://static.mtgstocks.com/cardimages/489717.png'}}},.......
```

### Explanation

Using `start_urls` populates the start_url's list with requests. Here I'm specifying the first HTTP request for the first table. There are several URLs like `https://api.mtgstocks.com/analytics/mostplayed/1` that give you access to the other tables on the page.

I'm doing a scrapy request and using parse as the callback. The `response.json()` converts the JSON object to a python dictionary, only available in scrapy v2.2+ though. Which you can then use to either yield a dictionary or you could use items to specify what data you want.

Comment: Thank you so much, that work perfect for me! Now I just have to learn how to parse the json data. Which I am sure will be the easier part. I really appreciate it